# Remove sinewave in AudioKit?

Tags: swift, audiokit

Most of the time I'm thankful for the "warning" sinewave that plays when AudioKit can't find an audio file or runs into playback issues.  It's great for troubleshooting!  Sometimes I'd like to not have it as an option, however.

I understand that if my code is great it wouldn't be a problem :).  That being said, is there a way to turn this on/off?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a behavior of the underlying Apple sampler and I don't think there's much we can do on the AudioKit level to prevent it.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka thanks for the info!